# MVC3 EditorFor losing value on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've created and date editorfor template but the value is getting lost on postback. Please can anyone help?

Here's my Date.cshtml stored in the 'shared/editortemplates' folder:

```
    @model DateTime

<div class="input-append">
    <input type="text" class="input-small datePicker" id="@ViewBag.Id" name="@ViewBag.Id" />
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
```

Here's the view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RequiredByDate, new { Id = "RequiredByDate" })
```

And the property on the viewmodel:

```
    [Display(Name = "Required by date")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required by date is required.")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime RequiredByDate { get; set; }
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've not set the value on the input. what an idiot.

```
<input type="text" class="input-small datePicker" id="@ViewBag.Id" name="@ViewBag.Id" value="@Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")" />
```